# Animate navbar collapse using pure JS & CSS

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to remove jquery from my bootstrap template as i don't use JS Components. So I removed it and added fallback code for navbar-toggle in pure JS (check attatched JSFiddle).
Now I want to animate the navbar toggle (using CSS or pure JS).

I tried transition property with max-height. But i don't know the final height as there's a dropdown inside. SO if I use some big height, then the collapse is delayed.

I have created a JSFiddle using an example template from getbootstrap: https://jsfiddle.net/c5f82stw/

```js
// Navbar and dropdowns
var toggle = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-toggle')[0],
  collapse = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-collapse')[0],
  dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown');;

// Toggle if navbar menu is open or closed
function toggleMenu() {
  collapse.classList.toggle('collapse');
  collapse.classList.toggle('in');
}

// Close all dropdown menus
function closeMenus() {
  for (var j = 0; j < dropdowns.length; j++) {
    dropdowns[j].getElementsByClassName('dropdown-toggle')[0].classList.remove('dropdown-open');
    dropdowns[j].classList.remove('open');
  }
}

// Add click handling to dropdowns
for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  dropdowns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (document.body.clientWidth < 768) {
      var open = this.classList.contains('open');
      closeMenus();
      if (!open) {
        this.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-toggle')[0].classList.toggle('dropdown-open');
        this.classList.toggle('open');
      }
    }
  });
}

// Close dropdowns when screen becomes big enough to switch to open by hover
function closeMenusOnResize() {
  if (document.body.clientWidth >= 768) {
    closeMenus();
    collapse.classList.add('collapse');
    collapse.classList.remove('in');
  }
}

// Event listeners
window.addEventListener('resize', closeMenusOnResize, false);
toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu, false);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <!-- Static navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="./">Default <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
          <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>

  <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Navbar example</h1>
    <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static navbar and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
    <p>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/#navbar" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not want I wanted. I was looking for something JS.

Fine Tune max-height to your needs. And the dropdown would need extra height to work. Keep that in mind.

```
.navbar-collapse.in 

    max-height: 65em;
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g3hwf2yo/2/

```
.navbar-collapse{
    max-height: 0px;
transition: max-height 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
background: #d5d5d5;
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}
.navbar-collapse.in {

    max-height: 65em;
    transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

This uses cubic bezier to fine tune the animation.

```
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <!-- Static navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="./">Default <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
          <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>

  <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Navbar example</h1>
    <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static navbar and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
    <p>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/#navbar" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

Finally JS

```
// Navbar and dropdowns
var toggle = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-toggle')[0],
  collapse = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-collapse')[0],
  dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown');;

// Toggle if navbar menu is open or closed
function toggleMenu() {
  collapse.classList.toggle('collapse');
  collapse.classList.toggle('in');
}

// Close all dropdown menus
function closeMenus() {
  for (var j = 0; j < dropdowns.length; j++) {
    dropdowns[j].getElementsByClassName('dropdown-toggle')[0].classList.remove('dropdown-open');
    dropdowns[j].classList.remove('open');
  }
}

// Add click handling to dropdowns
for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  dropdowns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (document.body.clientWidth < 768) {
      var open = this.classList.contains('open');
      closeMenus();
      if (!open) {
        this.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-toggle')[0].classList.toggle('dropdown-open');
        this.classList.toggle('open');
      }
    }
  });
}

// Close dropdowns when screen becomes big enough to switch to open by hover
function closeMenusOnResize() {
  if (document.body.clientWidth >= 768) {
    closeMenus();
    collapse.classList.add('collapse');
    collapse.classList.remove('in');
  }
}

// Event listeners
window.addEventListener('resize', closeMenusOnResize, false);
toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu, false);
```

Have A nice day!